# How to understand "(Editable) super.getText();"

Tags: java, android, operator-precedence

Editable is an interface, the code as follows is a method of `EditText` class, which shows in the android source code:

```
public Editable getText() {
    return (Editable) super.getText();
}
```

i want to make it clear that how to understand the code `(Editable)super.getText()`, i have two ways to understand the line of code:

1.cast `super` class of `EditText`(the super class of EditText is TextView) to `Editable` , then invoke the getText() method with `Editable`,

2.invoke the `getText()` method with the super class(TextView), then cast the return class to `Editable`

which one is right? According to the operator precedence, the operator `()` `.`  both have the highest precedence, and the associativity is left, so thought may be the first way is right. But it made me more confused. you know, the super class of `EditText` is `TextView`, and i made a cast from `TextView` to `Editable`? `TextView` has nothing to do with `Editable`, how can it cast successfully?

Comment: Are you sure it is EditView class?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's `EditText` . thx :)@RajdeepDua

Comment: @MarkZar: I edited your question to say `EditText`.

Comment: thanks a lot :-) @ MisterSquonk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TextView has nothing to do with Editable, how can it cast successfully?

The return type of `TextView.getText()` is `CharSequence` and `Editable` is a sub-class of `CharSequence`.

Therefore...

```
return (Editable) super.getText();
```

...is simply casting a `CharSequence` (returned by the call to `super.getText()`) to an `Editable`.

Comment: you mean that, a base-class(`CharSequence`) can be casted to the sub-class(`Editable`) ? i made a test just now: 
    class A {};
    class B extends A{};
    public class Src {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  A a = new A();
  B b = (B)a;
     }
    };
Here got a `java.lang.ClassCastException`, but cast B to A is ok. why?

Comment: In reality, `Editable` and `CharSequence` are `interfaces` rather than `classes`. The Android docs say that `Editable` is a sub-class of `CharSequence` but actually `Editable` implements `CharSequence` rather than extends it. Interfaces in Java are subtly different from classes - if one interface implements another then they can be cast without the same restrictions as classes.

Comment: thanks a lot !  i made another simple test: `interface A{};`  `interface B extends A{};`  `class Implement_A implements A {};`  and then write codes in the main method: `A a = new Implement_A();` `B b = (B)a;` , then also got *** java.lang.ClassCastException***, why is it wrong? arent these codes i wrote above similar to thoes android source codes?

Answer (score 0):

It casts the result of `super.getText()` to `Editable`.

What's confusing you is that while parentheses are used to achieve both grouping and typecasting, in this case it is being used as the type-casting operator, which has lower precedence (equal to the `new` operator, I believe).

(I couldn't find the appropriate table on the official site, but here's one that seems to be correct: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

Answer (score 0):

Calls the getText() of the super class and casts it to Editable